# How to pass variable inside an array Vue

Tags: vue.js

How can I pass a variable from Images Array to access the display different image everytime I press the next button? I am new to vue js, I could use some help.

```
<template>
  <div class="background" :style="{backgroundImage: `url(${Images[number]})`}">
    <div v-on:click="next" class="nextButton"><p>&gt;</p></div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

this is the array

```
data: () => ({
    Images:[ Image1, Image2, Image3],
```

this is my next script code

```
  methods:{
    next()
    { 
      var number = 0;

      if(number > 2){
        number == 0;
      }
      else{
        number ++;
      }
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is everytime when you call the **next** method, you initialize the number to be zero. Please check the correct solution below

```
data: () => ({
    Images:[ Image1, Image2, Image3],
    number: 0, // Change added
    })
```

and the method would be like

```
methods:{
    next()
    { 
      if(this.number >= this.Images.length){ // Change added
        this.number = 0; // Change added
      }
      else{
        this.number += 1; // Change added
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much sir now I understand how it works.

Comment: Great!! I'm glad that helped